# How to fix powershell problem automate login button press

Tags: html, powershell

Im trying to run a powershell to auto populate the username and password then click the login button. I've managed to get it to populate the 2 fields but cannot work out how to get the login button to function.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6 offset3 login-form">
        <img src="./Data Retrieval_files/dataret-logo.png" alt="Direct Finance Group" href="/">                                        
        <form action="https://www.dfcdata.co.uk/2/" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="has-validation-callback">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span2">
                    <h2>My Login</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="span4">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="username" name="username" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off">
                </div>
                <div class="span4">
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" name="password" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off">
                    <a href="https://www.dfcdata.co.uk/2/forgotten-password" style="color: #cccccc;text-decoration: none">Forgotten Password?</a>
                </div>
                <div class="span2">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn dfc-btn red" name="login" value="login">Login</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem line in powershell is:

```
$Link=$ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("input") | where-object {$_.type -eq "btn dfc-btn red"}

$Link.click()
```

The error I'm getting on the click of the login is:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:1
+ $Link.click()
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `getElementsByTagName("button")` instead of `getElementsByTagName("input")`?

Comment: I tested it with button but that didnt work either